# Solving XNA Content Loader InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I've found StackOverflow quite a helpful reference in the past, and now that I've come up against an obstacle of my own, thought I'd try posting here.

My issue is that whenever my game attempts to load a SoundEffect file, it crashes with an InvalidOperationException (detail message: an unexpected error has occurred).  This game is being written on the XNA 4.0 framework, in C# with Visual Studio 2010 express as my IDE.  The sound effects being loaded are all .wav files, and are added into the game's Content project.

I've checked the board and tried the following suggestions:

- Confirm content.rootDirectory it set - it is set to "Content"
- Confirm content.load<> is accessing the resource via the correct path.  Using reflection, I got the current directory for the application, and then used the rootdirectory + the path it was trying to access.  The file definitely exists, is accessible, and is in that location.
- Ensure ContentManager content is not null - confirmed using debugging, and that would throw a different exception anyway.
- Confirm WAV is in 8 or 16 bit PCM.  Confirmed.
- Possible header corruption?  This error occurs on any and all sound effects I attempt to load, so it is not a header issue pertaining to one file.

Oddly enough, this error seems to have come out of nowhere.  It was working without problem for the past week, today its freaking out - and I haven't made any changes that would affect the content load process.

Here's the code throwing the error:

```
public void LoadSoundEffect(ContentManager content, String assetPath)
{
    if (content != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(assetPath) == false)
    {
        // This next line throws the exception.
        SoundEffect effectLoader = content.Load<SoundEffect>(assetPath);
        soundLibrary.Add(assetPath, effectLoader);
    }
}
```

Here's the stacktrace:

> at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Helpers.ThrowExceptionFromErrorCode(Int32 error)
>   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect.AllocateFormatAndData(Byte[] format, Byte[] >  data, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect.Create(Byte[] format, Byte[] data, Int32 
>    offset, Int32 count, Int32 loopStart, Int32 loopLength, TimeSpan duration)
>   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect..ctor(Byte[] format, Byte[] data, Int32 
>    loopStart, Int32 loopLength, TimeSpan duration)
>   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.SoundEffectReader.Read(ContentReader input, 
>    SoundEffect existingInstance)
>   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentReader.InvokeReader[T](ContentTypeReader 
>    reader, Object existingInstance)
>   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentReader.ReadObjectInternal[T](Object 
>    existingInstance)
>   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentReader.ReadObjectT
>   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentReader.ReadAssetT
>   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.ReadAsset[T](String assetName, 
>    Action`1 recordDisposableObject)
>   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.Load[T](String assetName)
>   at SerializableDataTypes.AudioManager.LoadSoundEffect(ContentManager content, String 
>    assetPath) in C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Res Judicata 
>    Chapter1\SerializableDataTypes\Script Elements\AudioManager.cs:line 78

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer - I'm completely stumped on this, and it's a really frustrating error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for curiosities sake, can you attempt loading your sound effect slightly differently.

```
SoundEffect effect = content.Load<SoundEffect>(String.Format(@"{0}", soundEffectPath))
```

I have had issues in the past loading certain content types when not using a string literal.

Comment: Sure, I could try that.  I seem to have gotten it to work (for now) by rebooting my system, but every now and then, when I have alternate audio running, it still crashes with that message.  I'll see if I can re-create that problem after making the fix!